# When two Bluetooth devices are connected, does either of them reply to any Inquiry scan, or send an Inquiry?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, handshake

I am trying to answer the following question?

When two Bluetooth devices are connected, does either of them reply to any Inquiry scan, or send an Inquiry?

I had a few experiments and my answer is no. I connected two BT devices and try to pick any BT device nearby by my other phone which it did not detect any of them.

It would be great if you could also support your answer by a referencable document.

I have looked at several docs like these:
http://essay.utwente.nl/59681/1/MA_scriptie_A_Franssens.pdf
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-0-387-75462-8_20.pdf

but could not find a straight answer.

Comment: Yes, Bluetooth device can scan/enquiry and send scan/enquery response when connected. However, most cells designed so that it can be discovered only when you have Bluetooth settings opened. This is not Bluetooth limitation but OS design.

Comment: Thanks, @MikePetrichenko, could you please support your answer with a referencable doc. I really need the answer to be referencable. I would like to accept this as an answer if you could kindly provide a link. Thanks again

Comment: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification

Comment: Good link, thanks, I found one master and several slaves, so why the multipoint module is needed for multiple concurrent connections if this capability exist in the BT standard?

Comment: master/slave selected and can be changed during/after connection. It does not matter what device role is during discovering (inquiry). What is "multipoint module"?

Comment: https://phiaton.com/bluetooth-multipoint-pairing-what-is-it-and-how-does-it-work/   and here   https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/LWSDSBTM44x.pdf   please see the second page-category column

Comment: This is not Bluetooth limitations. This is devices limitations. And it is absolutely reasonable why headphone or mouse pairis with only single device. But if you want there is no limitations to design such mouse or keyboard or headphone or anything else that can pair with more than single device. Once again: this is just how the hardware designed by its producer. Not Bluetooth limitations.

Comment: Your answer made the concept clearer for me. could you please put them as an answer, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Bluetooth device can scan/enquiry and send scan/enquery response when connected. However, most cells designed so that it can be discovered only when you have Bluetooth settings opened. This is not Bluetooth limitation but OS design.

If we are talking about headsets (or keyboard or any other HID device) then this is reasonable why manufacturer made it so it can pair/work with only single device. But this is just a manufacturer decition and made so by design. It is not Bluetooth limitations. If you need you can design such headset that can be paired and connected to few devices t the same time.

On high-level Bluetooth device can be in Discoverable and/or in Connectable modes. Discoverable mode makes device visible to other devices. Connectable mode allows to connect to the device.

Usually manufacturer design it so that is device is not paired (or when you press special button or open Bluetooth settings on cell) it stays in Discoverable mode. So other devices can discover (find) the headset/cell. Once you paired with your device the Discoverable mode switched off. So now you can connect to device (cause during pairing the MAC is stored and you do not need to rediscover the device).

Once you connected the device turns Connectable mode off so others can't find and connect to it.

But once again. This is how manufacturer designed device. It is not Bluetooth limitation.

[Bluetooth Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification)

Answer (score 1):

I know that you can connect and interact with multiple bluetooth low energy  devices without problems. I myself connected to at least three ble devices and could easily receive and send data.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrey, I connected my BT headset to my phone and start playing music. My other phone did not pick any of them. I did another experiment, I connect my Garmin GPS to my phone and again scan the area by my other phone, it did not pick any of them. Garmin also says this:https://support.garmin.com/en-GB/?faq=IQWVBKIlCm98v5CMATDw3A   I guess it is not possible for all devices unless they have Multipoint functionality. Just out of curiosity, Do the master automatically connect to all the slaves or you need to pair them one by one?